# Appending a numpy array to a list generating a 1-D array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have almost 8620 3-D numpy arrays. But when i am appending them to the list i am getting a single array containing only one 1-D array (i.e. the total no of numpy arrays). This is what i have tried so far.

```
x_train=[]
for root, _, file_names in os.walk(spectrograms_path):
  for file_name in file_names:
    file_path = os.path.join(root, file_name)
    spectrogram = np.load(file_path,allow_pickle=True)
    x_train = np.array(spectrogram)
    x_train = x_train[..., np.newaxis]
    print(x_train.shape)
```

I dont know what i am doing wrong. I am new to python, so any kind of help would be greatly appreciatd. I tried `np.hstack` and `np.vstack` but both of them are just concatenating the arrays based on axis.

Comment: Where's the list append?

Answer (score 0):

At first you are defining `x_train` as a list:

```
x_train=[]
```

but then you are redefining it:

```
x_train = np.array(spectrogram)
```

You can try something like this:

```
x_arrays = []
for root, _, file_names in os.walk(spectrograms_path):
  for file_name in file_names:
    file_path = os.path.join(root, file_name)
    spectrogram = np.load(file_path,allow_pickle=True)
    x_train = np.array(spectrogram)
    x_train = x_train[..., np.newaxis]
    x_arrays.append(x_train)

# do with x_arrays whatever you want: stack, etc
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply, so what i want is bit different. Lets say i have two arrays of dimension 78x24x20 and 54x24x20. The final array which i want is 2x24x20, where 2 is the length of the array. But currently i am only getting the length of the list (2,0)

Comment: I don't quite understand what do you want. The length of any list is always one number so what does the (2, 0) mean? Also what do you want to do with the first dimension (78, 54) of two arrays ?

Comment: Hi i want to create a 3D array which will be fed into an auto encoder. So currently i have 8620 3D arrays. The problem is i cannot give them to the directly to the autoencoder as the dimensions of the array are different. Also i cannot pad the array as it is highly sensitive data. So i wanted to combine all of them into one single array. I tried to do that by appending the array to a list. But when i checked the shape of array inside the list i am getting only one dimension. I hope i was able to explain my problem

Comment: How do you plan to combine 8620 of 3D arrays into a single array if the shapes of 3D arrays can be different? By combining you mean that you want to get a 4D array?

Comment: The dimension of mnist dataset is 50000x28x28x1. Where 50000 is the total number of images in the training set, 28x28 is the input dimension of the images and the last one is the channel as it is a gray-scale image. I want something similar. For my problem it should be 8620x24x20x1

Comment: If your 3D arrays have the same last 2 dim then can use `np.vstack`  like this `np.vstack((np.zeros((78, 24, 20)), np.zeros((54, 24, 20))))` . You can add to my example `combined = np.vstack(x_arrays)` in the end